# Roots of 2 Term Polynomials with Adjacent Powers Plus Constant

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to figure out if there is a general approach for finding roots of polynomials of the form:

$ax^{k+1} + bx^k + c$

For positive integers $k$. If it makes the problem different/easier the coefficient $a$ is always 1, $b$ is always positive, and $c$ is always negative.

You could solve it using the usual methods for $k \in \{1,2,3\}$. However, in those situations the computations can be kind of complicated/tedious and I was hoping some of the additional structure on the coefficients and the sparsity of the polynomial would give a more simple solution.

**Edit (This is incorrect, but leaving it here as someone commented on it):** I realized you could change variables from $x^k \rightarrow u$, then the equation becomes a quadratic in $u$:

$ax^{k+1} + bx^k + c \rightarrow au^2 + bu + c$. The solutions for this are the quadratic formula:

$u_0 = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$, then you get $x_0 = \sqrt[k]{u_0} = \sqrt[k]{\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}}$.

Which I think is what I was looking for.

Comment: If $u=x^k$, then $u^2=x^{2k}$, so it doesn’t become a quadratic unless $k=1$.

Comment: Ah, you're right.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could do something analogous.

For $k$ odd set $u = x^\frac{k+1}{2}$, then $x^{k+1} = u^2$. The $x^k$ term is equal to $\frac{u^2}{x}$, where $x = \sqrt[\frac{k+1}{2}]{u}$. This means that the $x^k = \frac{u^2}{x} = u^2 u^\frac{-2}{k+1}$.

Then our original polynomial becomes $au^2 + bu^2u^\frac{-2}{k+1} + c$. I don't know if this is more useful, but you could do something similar with even k.

Comment: Just stating the obvious, in case it helps: If $a=1$, then $b $ is the sum of the roots and $c $ is the product of the roots.  If $c $ is an integer or rational number, then a prime factorization of c or c's numerator and denominator may help.

Comment: $c$ is a negative integer, for the specific problem I'm working on it is $-2k$.

Comment: I am afraid that, for any $k>3$, you will never get analytical solutions and numerical methods would be needed. If $a$ and $b$ are positive and $c$ negative, I suppose that nice bounds could be found and Newton method would converge quite fast.

Comment: So I know I can get to an equivalent of Glasser's equation  (5) for the roots of your trinomial following his derivation in this paper, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700002879 , if I start with the substitution $N = k+1$ and $y=1/x $.  Getting to the finite sum of hypergeometric functions could be trickier though.  I get the gist of what had to be done, but the details are a bear.  I'll post what I figure out in a day or two.  If you can deal with stopping at the infinite sum for the roots, ala Glasser's equation (5), then it's easy.

Comment: I don't know if that is useful practically for me, because it wouldn't take much less time than just numerical root finding, but it's interesting anyway.